# IF and VLOOKUP in worksheet change macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet, small sample below, the actual is over 100 rows.

[image: Timesheet]

I have a worksheet change macro for when the week number is changed in B3.

```
If Target.Address = Range("$B$3").Address Then

    Range("C5:I7").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A5,'[NightRota.xlsx]" & Target.Value & "'!$A:$I,C$1,0)"
    Range("C8:I11").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A8,'[DayRota.xlsx]" & Target.Value & "'!$A:$J,C$2,0)"

End If
End Sub
```

My problem is that as employees leave or join and i add or remove them i have to continually change the range for the formulae.

What i am hoping for is that someone can help me add an IF statement to the formula depending on the value in column B, Day or Night. At the moment i have to ensure column B is filtered to ensure the correct formula goes in the correct cells.

Thanks in advance.

I've had some success, this is what I have now

```
If Target.Address = Range("$C$3").Address Then

    Range("D5:J91").Formula = "=IF($C5=""Night"",VLOOKUP($A5,'[NightRota.xlsx]" & Target.Value & "'!$A:$I,D$1,0))"
    Range("D5:J91").Formula = "=IF($C5=""Days"",VLOOKUP($A5,'[DayRota.xlsx]" & Target.Value & "'!$A:$J,D$2,0))"

End If

End Sub
```

Unfortunately when i run the code the second formula overwrites the first formula, can anyone help me out? The cell references are different from the first code as I'm using the full spreadsheet and not just the sample i posted in the pic.

Comment: It's better if you have a crack yourself first and then ask for help. Consult the formula help in Excel. If you're using VBA I think you should be ok.

Comment: I can put a formula into the sheet such as =IF(C5="Night",VLOOKUP($A5,'[NightRota.xlsx]23'!$A:$I,C$1,0)) which works fine but the sheet number "23" changes from week to week. I just can't get my head round how to put this formula into the worksheet change as i get a debug error. I've also edited the original post as i had the wrong cell for the lookup.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to work it out.

Thanks for the Input, You learn something new everyday as they say.

```
If Target.Address = Range("$C$3").Address Then

    Range("D5:J91").Formula = "=IF($C5=""Night"",VLOOKUP($A5,'[NightRota.xlsx]" & Target.Value & "'!$A:$I,D$1,0),VLOOKUP($A5,'[DayRota.xlsx]" & Target.Value & "'!$A:$J,D$2,0))"


End If

End Sub
```